# Issues with Proguard and obfuscation of Javascript code

Tags: android, proguard, android-obfuscation

In my android app I have a part that is a webview that send the application some javascript code.
And the obfuscation when I build for release is not listening to me :(
My proguard is looking like this:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
-keepattributes *JavascriptInterface*

-keep public class com.myPackage.MapFragment$JavascriptCallback
-keep public class * implements com.myPackage.MapFragment$JavascriptCallback
-keepclassmembers class com.myPackage.MapFragment$JavascriptCallback {
   <methods>;
}
```

And my class looks like this:

```
class MapFragment() {

@JavascriptInterface
inner class JavascriptCallback{
    fun postMessage() {
        
    }
 }
}
```

I also have tried with an independent class, but is not working.
I'm about to disable the minifying.